# Does mechanical resonance of an object changes in different surrounding medium?

Tags: waves, acoustics

When comparing mechanical resonance of an object (for example string) in air and in water, does the resonance frequency changes? My guess is that it does change because the surrounding medium will slow it down. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surrounding medium causes a damping effect on the motion of the object, which tends to kill the vibrations. Assuming linear damping and harmonic motion in one dimension, the forced oscillator equation
$$m x''(t)=-kx(t)-\gamma x'(t)+A\sin(\omega t)$$
has steady-state solution
$$x(t)=\frac{A }{\sqrt{\left(k-m\omega^2\right)^2+\gamma ^2 \omega ^2}}\sin \left(\omega t+\text{ArcTan}\left(k-m \omega ^2,-\gamma  \omega \right)
   \right)$$
and the amplitude prefactor $\frac{A }{\sqrt{\left(k-m\omega^2\right)^2+\gamma ^2 \omega ^2}}$ can be differentiated with respect to $\omega$ and set equal to zero to obtain
$$\omega_\text{max}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}-\frac{\gamma^2}{2m^2}}$$
which decreases as damping $\gamma$ increases. So yes, the resonance frequency decreases in the presence of a damping medium.

[Interestingly, while the resonance frequency decreases, the frequency of maximum power coupling remains the same](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109242/why-maximum-energy-transfer-at-natural-frequency-even-if-max-amplitude-occurs-be).

Comment: Thank you, how about if the medium is transferring wave to the object to vibrate it, will the resonance frequency of the object still be the same? Because the medium is the one acting on the object not the object acting on the medium.

Comment: @Kevin: I feel like the answer above should still approximately hold, but you might want to double-check with someone else who understands acoustics well. My guess is that in the case of a medium transferring vibrations to an object, the medium acts both as a driving force (sound waves travel through the medium and vibrate the object) and as a damping mechanism (the object has friction as it oscillates in the medium).